# Incrementing & decrementing timestamp value in hour format

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, vi

I have a start and end range of timestamp in the following format:

```
2015-05-07 12:00:00 and 2015-05-08 09:00:00
```

Now I want to get the list of timestamps between this range in the hour format, as below:

```
2015-05-07 12:00:00
2015-05-07 13:00:00
2015-05-07 14:00:00
-------------------
2015-05-08 08:00:00
2015-05-08 09:00:00
```

My problem starts with not being able to properly increment or decrement a timestamp value in the hourly format using a shell variable.

The following works:

```
CURRENT_EST_HOUR=`date -d '2015-05-08 12:00:00 1 hour' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"`
```

But if I try to substitute a variable in place of timestamp string, I get 'extra operand' or 'invalid date' error.

```
timestamp1='2015-05-08 12:00:00'
CURRENT_EST_HOUR=`date -d '${timestamp1} 1 hour' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"`
```

or

```
CURRENT_EST_HOUR=`date -d ${timestamp1}'1 hour' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"`
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Is there a better way to do this in Unix?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your system timezone affects result. To avoid this just add `--utc` flag to command and "UTC" timezone to time. Like this:

```
$ date --utc -d '2015-05-08 12:00:00 UTC + 1 hour' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"
2015-05-08 13:00:00
```

Comment: I was able to do it, using the following:

    CURRENT_EST_HOUR=`date -d '2015-05-08 12:00:00 1 hour ago' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"`
But if I substitute a variable in place of timestamp value then it isn't working. Syntax error saying, extra operand. How do I use variable in the above command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by a minor correction in the command as follows:

```
PREV_INS_TS=`date -d '2015-05-08 12:00:00 1 hour' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"`
```

The + before 1 hour was messing up the result. Maybe UTC conversion was taking place internally.

And for using a variable in place of timestamp string the following command works:

```
PREV_INS_TS=`date -d "${PREV_INS_TS}"'1 hour' +%Y-%m-%d" "%H":00:00"`
```